# overriding interface method

Tags: java, generics, inheritance, interface

For a interface such as

```
public interface something<T>
{
   public something<T> somemethod();
}
```

from what i understand the abstract method somemethod() needs to overridden with a method that returns an object implementing the interface. However, any attempts to do so have given me the "does not override the abstract method somemethod()" compiler error.

I've tried doing something like

```
public class someclass {
...
    public something<T> somemethod() { ... return new someclass(); }
...
or 
    public someclass somemethod() { ... return new someclass(); }
...
}
```

How exactly would i implement such a method?

Answer (score 3):

You're missing the generic declaration in your implementing class. Here's an example:

```
public interface Something <T> {

    public Something<T> someMethod();

}

class SomethingImplementation <T> implements Something <T> {

    @Override
    public Something<T> someMethod() {
        return null;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

All of these should compile:

```
class test<T> implements something<T>{
    public something<T> somemethod(){
        return new test<T>();
    }
}

class test1<T> implements something<T>{
    public test1<T> somemethod(){
        return new test1<T>();
    }
}   

class test2 implements something<Integer>{
    public something<Integer> somemethod(){
        return new test2();
    }
}

class test3 implements something<Integer>{
    public test3 somemethod(){
        return new test3();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, your `someclass` does not implement the interface in your code example above. You can make it implement the interface for a specific, concrete type, as in the following example, where `String` is used as the concrete type. The method then would need to return a `something<String>`.

```
public class someclass implements something<String> {
    public something<String> somemethod() {
        return new someclass();
    }
}
```

Or you could have class `someclass` have a type parameter and use that for the interface:

```
public class someclass<X> implements something<X> {
    public something<X> somemethod() {
        return new someclass<X>();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> from what i understand the abstract method somemethod() needs to
>   overridden with a method that returns an object implementing the
>   interface.

That is not correct. The method `somemethod` needs to return a `something<T>`.

Answer (score 0):

You also need to extend the interface with a generic, such as:

public class someclass implements something {
  public something somemethod() {
    ...
  }
}

Answer (score 0):

To override a method you have to implement a method with the same types of paramenters and the same type of return value.
`String something(){}` 
will be overriden by `String something(){}`
but NOT with `char[] something(){}` or `String something(int){}`

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, you need to implement interface something, You can do this in simple way:

```
public class someclass<T> implements something<T> {
    public something<T> somemethod() { ... return new someclass(); }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class someclass<T> extends something<T> {

public something<T> somemethod() { ... return new someclass<T>(); }}
```